# Salesforce CPQ Calculator Plugin - Get User Permissions

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins

In the CPQ Quote Calculator Plugin, I'd like to conditionally enable editing for a specific field based on the running user's permissions (whether or not they have been assigned a specific Perm Set).

I tried adding an apex post to the "isFieldEditableForObject" that would run once and set a static variable (so on next function call it won't run again), however the post is not executing when the function is called.  None of the console logs are showing up, so the code is not running as I would expect...  Below is my example, are we not allowed to make calls to apex within the isFieldEditableForObject function?  If not is there a better way to get a user's permissions when the "Edit Cart" page loads?

```
let ALLOW_OVERRIDE_PRICING_ON_CONTRACT_PND;

export function isFieldEditableForObject(fieldName, quoteOrLine, conn, objectName) {
    if(objectName == 'QuoteLine__c' && fieldName === 'My_Field__c'){
        if(ALLOW_OVERRIDE_PRICING_ON_CONTRACT_PND == null || ALLOW_OVERRIDE_PRICING_ON_CONTRACT_PND == undefined){
            try{
                conn.apex.post("/GetUserPermissions/", null, function (err, res) {
                    if(err){
                        console.error(err);// this line not appearing
                    }
                    let userPerms = JSON.parse(res.body);
                    console.log('userPerms: ' , userPerms);// this line not appearing
                    ALLOW_OVERRIDE_PRICING_ON_CONTRACT_PND = true;
                });
            }
            catch(e){
                console.error(e);// this line not appearing
            }
        }
    if(ALLOW_OVERRIDE_PRICING_ON_CONTRACT_PND !== true){
        return false;
    }
}
```

}